# How to fix Rmarkdown error "could not find the function". However notebook preview works

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, rnotebook

So i prepared notebook in R and then knitted it to html. Everything was perfectly fine, but later on when i updated data, so i changed one line of code, i started to get error:

```
Error in ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = fct_infreq(as.factor(worker)))): 
could not find function "ggplot" Calls: <Annonymous> ... handle
 -> withCallingHandlers -> withvisible -> eval ->eval
```

However, when i coppied the whole script to the notebok and created a preview it works perfeclty well, and also when i run this ggplot function separately it works.

```
ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = fct_infreq(as.factor(worker)))) +
  geom_bar(width = 0.5, color = "blue") +
  labs(x ="Worker", y = "Answers") +
  geom_text(stat ='count', aes(label = ..count.., vjust =-0.5)) +
  ggtitle("Total iterations")
```

The question is: why knitting to HTML doesnt work for me and what i am missing here

thanks!

Comment: Did you include ``library(ggplot2)` in your .Rmd script *before* calling `ggplot`?

Answer (score 1):

@dario's response should do the trick (don't forget to add `library(forcats)` as well to get the `fct_infreq()` function), and is probably a better practice with `ggplot2` than explicitly adding the package to every function e.g. `ggplot2::ggplot(mydata, ggplot2::aes(x = forcats::fct_infreq(as.factor(worker)))`.